# if number is the same as a box change its colour

Tags: php, css

I have stumbled across a little problem. my code so far auto generates all the days in the month into separate boxes. like a calendar format.

```
  $number     = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 7, 2016);

    // LOOP THROUGH THE NUMBER OF MONTHS USING FOR-LOOP AND CREATE
    // THE BOXES THAT YOU DESIRE (WITH CSS-CLASSES, THOUGH)
    $calBoxes   = "";

    //makes numbers 1 after the other
    for($cue=1; $cue<=$number; $cue++){

       //adds the date
        $fmtDay    = date("D", strtotime("2016-7-{$cue}"));

        //adds div for outside box 
        $calBoxes .= "<div id='box' class='date-box date-box-{$cue}'>" . PHP_EOL;
        $calBoxes .= "<span class='date-number date-number-{$cue}'>{$fmtDay}</span>" . PHP_EOL;
        $calBoxes .= "<span class='weekday weekday-{$cue} weekday-" . strtolower($fmtDay) . "'>{$cue}</span>" . PHP_EOL;
        $calBoxes .= "</div>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

the problem I'm having is I can't find a way to make a certain box a certain color depending on a number in a variable. say the number is 7 it will make the 7th box which the result being Thursday 7 a certain color. leaving the rest as default.

this is the css for the boxes

```
#box{
  background-color:black;
  width: 75px; height: 75px; 
  border: solid 1px white; display: inline-block;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

for the box number declared in a specific veriable it needs to change to green instead of black.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did to get it to turn the number specified in the variable green.

```
$number     = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 7, 2016);

        // LOOP THROUGH THE NUMBER OF MONTHS USING FOR-LOOP AND CREATE
        // THE BOXES THAT YOU DESIRE (WITH CSS-CLASSES, THOUGH)
        $calBoxes   = "";

        //makes numbers 1 after the other
        for($cue=1; $cue<=$number; $cue++){

           //adds the date
            $fmtDay    = date("D", strtotime("2016-7-{$cue}"));

            $var ="2";

     if ($var == $cue) $color = 'green';
    else {$color ='black';}

            $calBoxes .= "<div style= class='date-box date-box-{$cue}'>" . PHP_EOL;
            $calBoxes .= "<span style=\"color: $color;\" class='date-number date-number-{$cue}'>{$fmtDay}</span>" . PHP_EOL;
            $calBoxes .= "<span class='weekday weekday-{$cue} weekday-" . strtolower($fmtDay) . "'>{$cue}</span>" . PHP_EOL;
            $calBoxes .= "</div>" . PHP_EOL;
        }
        ?>
<div id=margindate>
```

Please feel free to edit the question to make it more understandable.